# Mysql and java socket parallel stress test

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, tcp, innodb

I have an a java tcp socket application.  Tcp communicator decodes the GPS location and inserts that data into the database and before inserting we do some selects and updates but all I do it using prepared statements. Right now, one thread of TCP communicator serves one device request.Immediately after creating the thread we get one connection from the pool. After decoding the GPS data is where we perform the multiple select, update and insert for each data. As number of devices are increasing, the number of concurrent connections to our Mysql database are also increasing.So I am trying to conduct a simulation and stress test something like below. The issue is that this is sequential test but in real environment the devices will be coming in parallel. How to achieve a near real stress situation for both mysql and java to find out how many inserts could mysql take in on second?

```
 public class stress1 extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.102", 8000);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
            out.println("$A12345,30061104075130528955N10024852E000068*03A1*");
            System.out.println(in.readLine() + i);
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
    }
```

Here is how my server socket looks like.

```
public class comm8888 {
    HikariDataSource connectionPool = null;
    private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }
    Connection dbconn = null;
    public void run() { // etc
     DataOutputStream w = null;
     DataInputStream r = null;  
     String message="";
     receivedSocketConn1.setSoTimeout(60000);
       dbconn = connectionPool.getConnection();
     dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
     try {
         w = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
         r = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));
         while ((m=r.read()) != -1){
             //multiple prepared based sql select,update and insert here.
         }
     }
     finally{
        try {
            if ( dbconn != null ) {
              dbconn.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
           if ( w != null ){
                w.close();
                r.close();
                receivedSocketConn1.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
      }
   }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new comm8888();
    }
    comm8888() {
      try {
          HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
                config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdata"); 
                config.setUsername("****"); 
                config.setPassword("****");      
                config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);      
          connectionPool = new HikariDataSource(config); // setup the connection pool           
       }
          catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
         }
          try 
          {
                   final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(8888);                
                   while (true){
                            try {
                                    Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
                                    new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                     
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                            }
                        }
          } 
          catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace(System.out);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert statements are really slow. I would not do it like that. I would first save all data in an arraylist and then load it up to the database  using something like LOAD DATA IN FILE . Can you not do that? If you want to see how bad creating insert statements are, just include them in your loop and you ll see the mess.

Comment: @Arminius I can keep them in an array the issue they are few thousand of unit will be connecting within a minute. Thus each will be sending individual data. But before that I need to run few select and update statement then finally do these insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution doesn't scale well. I would encapsulate the work to be done (GPS location of a device) in objects of some class, then put each unit of work in a queue.  Finally, one thread can process all the work sequentially, processing one request at a time.

If one thread can't keep up and your queue becomes full, then it is very easy to scale by adding more workers to process jobs from the queue. (or if one instance of MySQL can't handle all the inserts, you can also try for example horizontal sharding of your data and adding multiple MySQL instances).

this is some sample code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;


public class QueueingDatabaseProcessingExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        QueueingDatabaseProcessingExample a = new QueueingDatabaseProcessingExample();
        a.doTheWork();
    }

    private void doTheWork() throws InterruptedException {

        BlockingQueue<TcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1000);

        // add work to queue as needed
        blockingQueue.put(new TcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork("device id", 40.7143528, -74.0059731, 10));  // blocks if queue is full


        Connection connection;

        // get connection to the database from database pool

        // process requests one by one sequentially
        while (true) {
            TcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork tcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork = blockingQueue.take(); // blocks if queue is empty

            proccess(tcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork);
        }
    }

    private void proccess(TcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork tcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork) {
        // do queries, inserts, deletes to database
    }

}


/**
 * this class should have all the information needed to query/update the database
 */
class TcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork {

    private final String deviceId;
    private final double latitude;
    private final double longitude;
    private final int seaLevel;

    public TcpCommunicatorUnitOfWork(String deviceId, double latitude, double longitude, int seaLevel) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.seaLevel = seaLevel;
    }


}
```

Comment: thank you for idea. Actually currently I am running multithread application on the server where each client get connected it opens a new thread. So what is the drawback compare to your suggestion? You suggestion is about doing bulk insert into db is it? I think eventually it comes to the same the queue will be adding up right? So where is the socket connection done the problem is that the device does not close the socket for very long is that a good thing or bad?

Comment: creating and starting a new thread per client will cause your computer to run out of resources and is an unnecessary overhead, as your computer can't execute too many threads simultaneously. With my solution you control the total number of threads that are doing the actual work (processing, connecting to the database)

Comment: so with your idea you still have the multi thread for the socket? Cause I dont see the socket? So I guess after you receive the data you pump into a queue rite but wouldnt that slow down the process. So in case I stop my this application everything in the queue will do missing ? I am afraid all the inserts will be then slow down right?

Comment: I have updated my question below I have inserted how I do my server socket so maybe you can give me your idea based on your solution what to improvise on my solution?

Comment: If I understood correctly from your code, you are keeping a connection open between client and server until the server replies (this is a wrong approach). If the server takes more than 1 second to reply, then you need a different way to communicate between client and server (using a messaging queue for example)

Comment: yes I keeping the connection open between the client and server the problem the device does not close the connection is that a good solution I know theoretically this is bad that is why I added this receivedSocketConn1.setSoTimeout(60000);?  When you server take more than 1 second to reply ? Reply what ? What should I be doing please guide me the correct socket then?

Comment: any input based on my codes stated in my question? What best do you suggest I dont get you on the connection how to avoid multiple threads there?